# Align left and right

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to somehow align the text in divs so that it is exactly on the edges?

```css
.name {
  margin: 0 0 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
 }
  
.row {
  margin: 0 0 5px 10px;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

```html
<div class="name">Align</div>

<div class="row">
zxcsdz 123
</div>
<div class="row">
qwe 4561
</div>
<div class="row">
asdsq 789
</div>
```

Now in the answer we get like this

> zxcsdz 123
> qwe 4561
> asdsq 789

But it must be exactly along the edges, something like this

> zxcsdz   123
> qwe     4561
> asdsq    789

Comment: How does the system know where the right hand edge is to be? Is there some sort of container or is there a width set on row?

Comment: @AHaworth no, there is no container

Comment: So how does the system know where the right hand edge is to be?

Comment: @AHaworth apparently nothing, i need to add a container

Comment: Or set a width for the row class. Then look into flex and justify-content: space-between.

Comment: @AHaworth did it like this now, but it doesn't work, updated the snippet

Comment: It didn’t work because you haven’t used flex. Look into using flex box e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex The answers given so far require a change to the HTML which isn’t necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.  I would use something other than just divs to put text inside of so your HTML is more semantic.

```css
.name {
    margin: 0 0 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.row {
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">Align</div>

<div class="row">
    <div>
        zxcsdz
    </div>
    <div>
        123
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        qwe
    </div>
    <div>
        4561
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        asdsq
    </div>
    <div>
        789
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways to do it, but you cant seperate the words and the numbers as you want, because each phrase is like one piece in your code, so you cant do much with them unless u seperate them, put each in a diffrent element tag, like a P tag, then you can use flexbox to help you with this! see my code to get a better idea

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
.num {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="align">
    <p class="word">zxcsdz</p>
    <p class="word">qwe</p>
    <p class="word">asdsq</p>
  </div>
  <div class="align">
    <p class="num">123</p>
    <p class="num">4779</p>
    <p class="num">789</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways do do that. You can achieve it with two inline elements and then text-align. In my example I use the flexbox and then text align.

```css
.name {
  margin: 0 0 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
 }
  
.row {
  margin: 0 0 5px 10px;
  display:flex;
 }
.row .r1 {
  text-align: left;
  
}
.row .r2 {
  text-align: right;  
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">Align</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="r1">zxcsdz</div> 
  <div class="r2">123</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="r1">zxcsdz</div> 
  <div class="r2">123</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="r1">zxcsdz</div> 
  <div class="r2">123</div>
</div>
```